# Python3 run a complex shell command with multiple intended quotations

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, quoting

When i run from bash:

```
# su -c "psql -d mapping -c \"INSERT INTO mapping (ip,username) VALUES('1.2.3.4','test');\"" postgres
```

It works fine, but when i try from python:

```
subprocess.run("su -c \"psql -d mapping -c \"INSERT INTO mapping (ip,username) VALUES('1.2.3.4','test');\"\" postgres")
```

It fails, i have tried different quotation marks and all failing. Could you please help?

Comment: You are needing to pass the internal slashes to bash, so try \\\"INSERT......\\\"" postgres..... Notice the backslash-backslash -- the first one escapes the second,  the third one escapes the double quote inside the double-quoted command in bash.

Comment: still the same issue with:
  subprocess.call("su -c \"psql -d mapping -c \\\"INSERT INTO mapping (ip,username) VALUES('1.2.3.4','test');\\\"\" postgres")

Comment: Instead of calling subprocess.run, use a "print(...)" statement to print out what is getting output. Also, you say it fails -- what error message is being displayed?

Comment: if i run print() i got he following error: python3 search.py
  File "search.py", line 49
    print('su -c \"psql -d mapping -c \\\"INSERT INTO mapping (ip,username) VALUES('1.2.3.4','test');\\\"\" postgres")
                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: when run from subprocess.call i got error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:...............

Comment: Try this: print("su -c \\\"psql -d mapping -c \\\"INSERT INTO mapping (ip,username) VALUES('1.2.3.4','test');\\\"\\\" postgres")

Comment: OK, i was getting "No such file or dir" because used just "su", with "/bin/su" it's better, right now i got the error invalid syntax point at '1.2.3.4' part (the same call as original or with \\\\)

Comment: I am not executing that command, but the print statement I sent above matches what you say works on the command line. I have no further way to troubleshoot this as the output from the print statement matches the command you say works directly in Bash. Sorry I can not help further.

Comment: print command returns invalid syntax pointing to 1.2.3.4:  print('/bin/su -c \"psql -d mapping -c \\\"INSERT INTO mapping (ip,username) VALUES('1.2.3.4','test');\\\"\" postgres") . SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Notice how your print statement and mine differ.....I have added more slashes to mine in my previous comment.

Comment: OK, i am at the stage where print is working fine, and if i take print results and execute in bash it is working fine. But if i do replace print with subprocess.call it fails with "No such file or directory".

Comment: this is my current call from python: subprocess.call('/bin/su -c \"psql -d mapping -c \\\"INSERT INTO mapping (ip,username) VALUES(\'1.2.3.4\',\'test\');\\\"\" postgres')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions, depending on whether or not you use the shell from Python.  The trivial but inefficient solution is to pass the string with `shell=True` and basically just add Python quoting around it.

```
subprocess.run(r'''su -c "psql -d mapping -c \"INSERT INTO mapping (ip,username) VALUES('1.2.3.4','test');\"" postgres''', shell=True,
    # For good measure, you should check its status
    check=True)
```

More efficiently and perhaps in fact more readably, you can remove the shell from the equation, and split the command into strings yourself.

```
subprocess.run([
        'su', '-c',
        # The argument to "su -c" should be one string
        # Because we escaped the shell, the double quotes don't need escaping
        '''psql -d mapping -c "INSERT INTO mapping (ip,username) VALUES('1.2.3.4','test');"''',
        'postgres'],
    check=True)
```

Notice how with `shell=True` the first argument is a string which gets passed to the shell, whereas without it, you pass a list of tokens directly to the OS-level `exec()` or (somewhat less straightforwardly on Windows) `CreateProcess()`.  Notice also how in the first instance I used an `r'...'` string to avoid having Python meddle with the backslashes in the string.

Comment: For more on this, perhaps see also my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python